# Json deserialization data modification on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net-core, json.net

Let's say that I have a semi-complex json model like this:

```
      "Person": {
        "Name": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "Birth":{
          "Day": 3,
          "Month": 3,
          "Year": 1989
        },
        "Physical":{
          "General": {
            "Height": 176.0, // cm
            "Weigth": 70000.0 // gr
          },
          "Arm":{
            "Length": 82.0, // cm
            "HandLength": 18.0, // cm
            "HandWeight": 312.0 // gr
          },
          "Leg": {
            "Length": 89.0, // cm
            "FootLength": 25.0, // cm
            "FootWeight": 486.0 // gr
          }
        }
      },
     "Person": {........}
```

And I'm using a model like:

```
public class PersonModel 
{
    public class Birth
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Day")]
        public int Day { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Month")]
        public int Month { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Year")]
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class General
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Height")]
        public double Height { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Weigth")]
        public double Weigth { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Arm
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Length")]
        public double Length { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("HandLength")]
        public double HandLength { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("HandWeight")]
        public double HandWeight { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Leg
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Length")]
        public double Length { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("FootLength")]
        public double FootLength { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("FootWeight")]
        public double FootWeight { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Physical
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("General")]
        public General General { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Arm")]
        public Arm Arm { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Leg")]
        public Leg Leg { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Person
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Birth")]
        public Birth Birth { get; set; }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Physical")]
        public Physical Physical { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Person")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And let's say I have a controller method like:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PersonModel.Root>>> GetPeople(SomeRequestModel people, [FromQuery] LengthUnit length = LengthUnit.cm, [FromQuery] WeightUnit weight = WeightUnit.gr, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    // Generate the data in 'rawJson' variable
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<PersonModel.Root>>(rawJson);
    // Here, based on 'length' and 'weight' parameters, I need to convert units
    return result;
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum LengthUnit
{
    cm,
    foot
}
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum WeightUnit
{
    gr,
    pound
}
```

Based on controller parameters, I need to convert values. For example, if the request is like `/GetPeople?length=foot`

I need to return;

```
      "Person": {
        "Name": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "Birth":{
          "Day": 3,
          "Month": 3,
          "Year": 1989
        },
        "Physical":{
          "General": {
            "Height": 5.77428, // feet
            "Weigth": 70000.0 // gr
          },
          "Arm":{
            "Length": 2.69029, // feet
            "HandLength": 0.590551, // feet
            "HandWeight": 312.0 // gr
          },
          "Leg": {
            "Length": 2.91995, // feet
            "FootLength": 0.82021, // feet
            "FootWeight": 486.0 // gr
          }
        }
      },
     "Person": {........}
```

I understand that I can easily accomplish this by writing if-else statements after deserialization and modifying properties directly. On the other hand, I don't like the idea of doing this inside of my controller nor having a bulky helper method that I call after deserialization, referencing my deserialize object.

Just curious is there a good and clean way to accomplish this? I don't mind using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json.

Comment: Would you mind adding more property to your JSON result which can represent the intention clearly.

Comment: @D-Shih The intention is to pretty much convert unit of the values. Initially, data for length is in centimeters. In result, they are in feet.

Comment: Side point: that JSON isn't really valid, as `Person` is specified multiple times. Perhaps you wanted an array instead

Answer (score 1):

I would just to put this to getters/setters

```
public static convert=true;

public class General
    {
       private double _height;
       
        [JsonPropertyName("Height")]
        public double Height {
         get { return  convert? SmToFeet(_height) : _height ; }
         set  { _height=value; } 
       }
    
        [JsonPropertyName("Weigth")]
        public double Weigth { get; set; }
    }

private double SmToFeet( double num)
{
    return num/30.5;
}
```

the same for another properties. Or you can make convert in set if you are sure that you don' t need metric.